# Correct battery for Insignia Sports Tourer

Tags: battery, diesel, vauxhall, insignia

I have 2013 Insignia Elite CDTI AUTO diesel 1956cc. United Kingdom vehicle.

How to get the correct car battery and what specifications to look for while choosing the right battery?

I tried reading in [user manual](https://www.vauxhall.co.uk/content/dam/vauxhall/Home/PDFs/owners/owners-manuals/insignia/insignia-owners-manual-august-2012.pdf) but couldn’t find anything about battery size or type. Any help please

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

There's two things you need to know about batteries. First the physical size and secondly the CCA output. In some cases you might also need to know the power reserve (Amp Hour or AH). Luckily you have two sources to figure it out. First, look at the battery itself and get the model number off of it. Secondly, if you go to a parts store where they sell batteries, they'll be able to source the number for you.

Looking online, according to [this website](https://www.tayna.co.uk/car-batteries/enduroline/096/), the battery you're looking for should be an "096". If it has "start/stop" technology, it should still be a 096, but you'll need to look at the battery to see if it is an EFB or AGM style (versus a standard lead acid). In either case it should be labeled as to which one.

[This website](https://www.thebatteryguys.co.uk/car-batteries/vauxhall/insignia_241-5843/) tends to agree with the "096" however, it also gives a few more. In this case, they give dimensional sizes for the battery. You can measure yours and ensure what you're buying will match.

Comment: In addition, terminal location on the battery is also significant. Make sure the replacement battery's terminal locations and polarity are the same as the original battery's.